# How to display a table inside a table cell using Rdlc report

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, rdlc

Is there any way to display table inside a table cell using Rdlc report? If so please guide me as i am very new to Rdlc reports.

Regards
B Dharmaraju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of your issue, you can try two ways of doing it :

The easiest way is to use subreports. Check msdn here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348.aspx

Another way maybe harder is to generate dynamically the report (rdlc file). Don't forget it's only an XML file. You can make the one you want with Business Intelligence Studio and generate something like this with your own tool.